# Web add-In: how to download base64 encoded content in outlook on mac?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-mac

I want to implement a web add-in feature to download base64 encoded data. This works for OWA and windows client, but does not work in outlook on mac.

Can you explain how to download any base64 encoded data in outlook on mac?

#### Tested variants

##### FileSaver.js

```
<IconButton
  iconProps={{ iconName: 'Download' }}
  onClick={() => {
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, filename);
  }}
/>
```

Works on windows and OWA, but not in outlook on mac.

##### Object URL with Link

```
<a href={URL.createObjectURL(blobObject)} download={filename}>download</a>
```

Works on windows and OWA, but not in outlook on mac.

##### Data URL with Link

```
<a href={`data:;base64,${data}`} download={filename}>download</a>
```

Works on windows and OWA, but not in outlook on mac.

##### openBrowserWindow

I also tried to open a browser windown containing a data url

```
Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(`data:;base64,${data}`)
```

or a url created by `URL.createObjectURL()`

```
Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(`blob:https://localhost:3000/<uuid>`)
```

`URL.createObjectURL()` should not work, because if the use defined an other default browser than safari, this link is invalid.

Additionally `openBrowserWindow()` only works with urls starting with `http://` or `https://`. URLs starting with `data:` or `blob:` are not recognized and does not open a new new browser window.

Comment: Can you please provide a script lab snippet for what you have tried. It will be good for us to understand the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the behavior of script is not identical to an outlook add-in.
You can create a new add-in using yeoman generator and paste `<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh" download="test.txt">download</a>` in the app component.

Comment: Script lab provides an iframe which contains the script. When you insert the provided download a-element, the content opens in the iframe and the download attribute is ignored. When you insert the a-element within an addin, the content does not open in the same window and the download attribute is ignored aswell.